# Python - iterable, not NoneType

Tags: python

What does this mean ? **TypeError: pyautogui.click() argument after * must be an iterable, not NoneType**

error: pyautogui.click(*pos4)

My code:

```
repeat = 100

while repeat > 0:

    def retry(action, max_secs=120):
        start = datetime.now()
        res = None
        while (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() < max_secs:
            res = action()
            if res: break
        return res


    pos4 = retry(lambda: pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('nextMatch.PNG'))
    pyautogui.click(*pos4)

    time.sleep(1)

    repeat -= 1
```

Comment: The `*` is used to split an iterable object. In your case, the `pos4` variable is None. Can you check by printing the intermediate value of pos4?

Comment: Thank you, so I need to remove this: * ?

Comment: Try doing that, but I am a bit sure it would not work, You will be passing none type to pyautogui.click(). But, surely try once

Comment: Are you sure `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('nextMatch.PNG')` works? Looks like it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but see the changes :

```
repeat = 100

while repeat > 0:

    def retry(action, max_secs=120):
        start = datetime.now()
        res = None
        while (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds() < max_secs:
            res = action
            if res: break
        return res


    pos4 = retry(lambda: pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('nextMatch.PNG'))
    pyautogui.click(pos4)

    time.sleep(1)

    repeat -= 1
```